# Verilog equivalent for VHDL-2008 to_01 function

Tags: vhdl, verilog

Would it be safe to say that VHDL-2008's to_01 function doesn't require a direct translation in Verilog? After looking [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430670/vhdl-2008-to-01-conversion), one could assume that's the case. Please, let me know if I missed anything important.

Comment: How about simply using a 2 state type in SV (like bit, byte or int) and simply assigning a reg to it?

Comment: To which TO_01 overloaded function are you referring? There are ones that both map driving weak high and low values to forcing '1' and '0' values as well as type conversion.  Neither seem particularly applicable without example code (including context and/or declarations).